# Pass byte array to Azure storage queue

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, azure-storage-queues

I am using Go package `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` where I need to enqueue Protobuff to storage queue. But as per library documentation Enqueue function takes message as string only.

- From go library:

```golang
*func (m MessagesURL) Enqueue(ctx context.Context, messageText string, visibilityTimeout time.Duration, timeToLive time.Duration) (*EnqueueMessageResponse, error)*
```

Is there any way to enqueue protobuff byte array to Azure storage queue?

Library link:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-queue-go/azqueue#MessagesURL.Enqueue

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that the [Azure Storage Queue Go library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-queue-go) provides any built-in support for byte arrays (or Protobuf messages).

However, you can apply your own serialization and convert your Protobuf message to e.g. JSON using the [protojson package](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson), and then pass the resulting string to the [Enqueue method](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-queue-go/azqueue#MessagesURL.Enqueue):

```
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
[...]
jsonBytes, _ := protojson.Marshal(protoMessage)
json := string(jsonBytes)
[...]
messagesURL.Enqueue(ctx, json, time.Second*0, time.Minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the proto message into a buffer by using the `Marshal` function. https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/proto#Marshal

After that, you can create a textual representation of the message, using something like [base64](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/).